# Convert big collection into simple array

Tags: javascript, array, ecmascript-6

Is there a better way to do this?

```
const data = [{id: 1, name: 'item1'}, {id: 2, name: 'item2'}]
const a = []
data.forEach(x => { a[x.id] = x.name })
return a // ['1': 'item1', '2': 'item2']
```

Comment: Include the language as a tag and a little bit more info like what do you use this chunk of code for..

Comment: `['1': 'item1', '2': 'item2']` isn't a valid array. Did you mean `['1', 'item1', '2', 'item2']` or something else?

Comment: The answer of Joseph resume it all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Use [`array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) *and use an object*.

```
const a = data.reduce((items, item) => (items[item.id] = item.name, items), {});

// a = {1:{...}, 2: {...};
```

You can still use the bracket notation to access the items, i.e. `a[id]`.

A problem with using IDs as array indices is that you introduce gaps in the array. You also get a false array length. Take the following example:

```
const a = [];
a[999] = {/* User data */};
a.length // 1000;
```

You only added a single item, with id "999" but now the array reports 1000 in length. Items 0 to 998 are actually empty.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was not sure the solution was the reduce. You confirmed it with a perfect example.
I know about the length but the part of the code that deal with it is quit big. It's something I need to improve in time. :thumbsup: